# Need to find all the files from the huge list of directories in bash

Tags: bash, shell

Need to find all the files in a huge list of directories with some criteria such as all files starts with "sam" and ends with ".gz".Can someone help me with this in bash?

Comment: tree | grep Sam | grep .gz

Comment: How is this list of directories presented? Can you provide a small sample of the format?

Comment: @user1767754 Thanks, i have tried this as well but it's not traversing all the directories and exists after traversing few of them.I have around 500 + directories where I need do the find.

Answer (score 1):

From bash you can call the find command like so:

```
find . -name 'sam*.gz'
```

If it's a list of directories, you can iterate over them with a for loop:

```
for d in $DIRS; do
    find $d -name 'sam*.gz'
```

Where `$DIRS` contains a space-separated list, i.e.:

```
DIRS="dir1 dir2 dir3"
```

Comment: Thanks, Alex but find just exists after traversing through some directories and is not listing out the files for me as I  have a huge list of the directory structure.

Comment: We probably need a sample file/directory structure

Comment: for example /backup/build12/build13........build700 and under these directories I have files wherein some of the files  start with "sam" and end with ".gz"which I need to find

Comment: Can't reproduce your problem. I generated some random dirs with `for i in {0..600}; do mkdir $(pwgen -s 4 -n1); done`, then populated them with `find . -type d -exec touch {}/sam-$(pwgen 4 -n1)-file.gz \;` and I get 602 files when calling `find . -name 'sam*.gz' | wc -l`, which doubles for every call of the `touch` find exec. So at least in my case find isn't skipping dirs.

Comment: Thanks Alex for trying that out.I have symlinks as well for these directories so not sure if that is creating an issue.

Comment: Absolutely, that's critical information! You need to follow symlinks, i.e. `find -L`

Comment: ya I found out symlinks were creating an issue.Thanks a ton for helping out.

Comment: also `find -L $DIRS -name 'sam*.gz'` will work as a single command (if DIRS < ARG_MAX: ~ 2M)